# Blank line causes an indentation problem in the exam class

Tags: exam

I found a strange behavior in the exam document class.
What I am trying to achieve is formatting like this:

[image: Goal]

But when I add a blank line (indicated in the code below), I get formatting like this:
[image]

Is there something I can change (maybe in `\qformat`) to fix this behavior?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}    
\begin{document}

\qformat{\thequestion \, \thequestiontitle \hfill}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{A question}
\begin{parts}
\part thing 1
\end{parts}
\titledquestion{Another question}
% remove the blank line below and the problem disappears 

\begin{parts}
\part thing 2
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might add the blank line before `\titledquestion{Another question}`. Then you will have the desired output.

Comment: @bmv Why not just add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the blank line before `\titledquestion{Another question}`, you will have the desired output.

Comment: This certainly works, but the fact that a white space is required at all (and the behavior when it is missing) seems like a bug in the class and I'm hoping for an answer that helps me fix it.